# How to debug web project based on vue js on LG Web Os TV

Tags: vue.js, webos

I used Laravel with vue js for creating web site with listings, and faced with problem on LG tv based on Web OS 3.0 where listings or any elements which are generated using vue js templates does not work. Any ideas what could be wrong or how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

They have very old Browser. Better search for plain javascript solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open your website using the built-in webOS web browser there are no options to inspect/debug it unless you use a remote inspector like [vorlonjs](http://www.vorlonjs.io/#getting-started). I have used vorlonjs in similar scenarios, but I not sure if it would work on webOS TVs

If you are triying to use your own webOS smartTV app to open your website you must enable the [developer mode](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-test/) in your TV and [debug](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/sdk/tools/ide/debugging-your-app-inspectors/) your app in order to inspect your website

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Slick slider was the cause of my problem, switching to another vue carusel solved it.

Comment: I hope this is the same issue as mine lol

Answer (score 0):

With the `ares-cli`, you can debug your ipk the following way:

```
ares-inspect --device tv --app com.example.app --open
```

Comment: Hello. Please I do not understand. Please where do I run this code... I am using the emulator.